# How to update collection documents in firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a document field and I've tried the following code but it doesn't update.

can anyone give me a solution, please?

My Code:

```
var snapshots = _firestore
        .collection('profile')
        .document(currentUserID)
        .collection('posts')
        .snapshots();

    await snapshots.forEach((snapshot) async {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.documents;

      for (var document in documents) {
        await document.data.update(
          'writer',
          (name) {
            name = this.name;
            return name;
          },
        );
        print(document.data['writer']);
       //it prints the updated data here but when i look to firebase database 
       //nothing updates !
      }
    });
```

Comment: try `document.setData(Map);` instead of `document.data.update`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For cases like this, I always recommend following the exact types in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html), to see what options are available. For example, a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)'s `data` property is a `Map<String, dynamic>`. To when you call `update()` on that, you're just updating an in-memory representation of the document, and not actually updating the data in the database.

To update the document in the database, you need to call the [`DocumentReference.updateData` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/reference.html). And to get from the `DocumentSnapshot` to a `DocumentReference`, you call the [`DocumentSnapshot.reference` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/reference.html).

So something like:

```
document.reference.updateData(<String, dynamic>{
    name: this.name
});
```

---

Unrelated to this, your code looks a bit non-idiomatic. I'd recommend using [`getDocuments`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) instead of `snapshots()`, as the latter will likely result in an endless loop.

```
var snapshots = _firestore
        .collection('profile')
        .document(currentUserID)
        .collection('posts')
        .getDocuments();

await snapshots.forEach((document) async {
  document.reference.updateData(<String, dynamic>{
    name: this.name
  });
})
```

The difference here is that `getDocuments()` reads the data once, and returns it, while `snapshots()` will start observing the documents, and pass them to us whenever there's a change (including when you update the name).

Comment: After doing this, it returned "2 positional argument (s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments." and this "The argument type 'Future <Null> Function (dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable <dynamic>'." on the following line `forEach ((document) async {`. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, is there any performance/cost difference between using : 
Reference to update data : postReference.update(map) 
versus using Id:
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts') 
    .doc('some_id')
    .update(map);

Comment: Both operations perform a single write operation to a single document, so will be charged the same.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2021:

Lot of things have changed in the API, for example, `Firestore` is replaced by `FirebaseFirestore`, `doc` is in, etc.

- **Update a document**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('some_id') // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
      .update({'key' : 'value'}) // <-- Updated data
      .then((_) => print('Updated'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Update failed: $error'));
  ```
- **Update nested value in a document:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('some_id') // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
      .update({'key.foo.bar' : 'nested_value'}) // <-- Nested value
      .then((_) => print('Updated'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Update failed: $error'));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the following language-specific `update()` methods:

```
final washingtonRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("cites").doc("DC");
washingtonRef.update({"capital": true}).then(
    (value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
    onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"));
```

##### Server Timestamp

> You can set a field in your document to a server timestamp which tracks when the server receives the update.

```
final docRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("objects").doc("some-id");
final updates = <String, dynamic>{
  "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};

docRef.update(updates).then(
    (value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
    onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"));
```

##### Update fields in nested objects

> If your document contains nested objects, you can use "dot notation" to reference nested fields within the document when you call update():

```
// Assume the document contains:
// {
//   name: "Frank",
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" }
//   age: 12
// }
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .doc("frank")
    .update({"age": 13, "favorites.color": "Red"});
```

##### Update elements in an array

> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element.

```
final washingtonRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"]),
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  "regions": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["east_coast"]),
});
```

##### Increment a numeric value

> You can increment or decrement a numeric field value as shown in the following example. An increment operation increases or decreases the current value of a field by the given amount.

```
var washingtonRef =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update(
  {"population": FieldValue.increment(50)},
);
```