# Why can't my Firebase Cloud Firestore Collection update (.update) when I have already created one (.set)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

'I have a Firebase Cloud Firestore Collection. When I am trying to update it, it can't find it. I can however see the newly created file in my collection. Anyone who knows how to fix this? I am fairly new in coding. Thank you in advance.

This the part of the code where we get the error, it is also mentioned elsewhere:'

```
class DatabaseService {
final String? uid;
DatabaseService({this.uid});
//collection reference
final CollectionReference listenCollection =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('listen');

Future updateUserData(String status, String name, int score) async {
  return await listenCollection.doc(uid).set({
    'status': status,
    'name': name,
  'score': score,
});
}

Future updateName(String name) async {
  return await listenCollection.doc(uid).update({'name': name});
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> get listen {
  return listenCollection.snapshots();
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017373/how-to-update-collection-documents-in-firebase-in-flutter.